# Is there a way to override the url while calling model.destroy in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Rigt now i am calling model.destroy(), a DELETE request to the server side

I want to override the url call while doing destroy, I wont be able to change the urlRoot.

Is there any way ?

Thanks,
Prats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass it when calling `destroy`.

`this.model.destroy( { url: "your-custom-url/" } );`

Comment: This will usually represent a bad violation of MVC as the model should encapsulate this knowledge in a single place. This approach would leak the custom URL out into views/controllers. Not that it is categorically bad design in every app, just for the typical designs, I would recommend against this.

Comment: totally agree - overriding the destroy method is definitely the preferable way otherwise it's just writing jQuery spaghetti-like code in Backbone :)

Answer (score 17):

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    destroy: function (options) {
        var opts = _.extend({url: '/destroy/' + this.id}, options || {});
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, opts);
    }
)};
```

All AJAX-based interactions are ultimately handled by `Backbone.sync` which takes an options object where the URL can be provided if backbone's default URL scheme doesn't work for your server.

Comment: Would be even better if you allowed the options to pass through as follows:

`destroy: function (options) {return Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, _.extend({url: '/destroy/' + this.id}, options)); }`